# Java - New line loop

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I have an array with types and numbers and when printing this is the outcome:

```
    car:1 car:2 car:3 boat:1 boat:2 boat:3 plane:1 plane:2 plane:3
```

I am looking for a way to determine when the type changes, and then make a new line. which means to print a "\n" after car:3 (and boat:3) so all the vehicles are on their own row.

I am printing all these items with a for-loop like this:

```
 for(Types filename: TypeTable)
    {
        Scanner s;
        s = new Scanner(filename.toString());
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.print(s.nextLine()+ " ");
        }
```

and I guess I am in need for some local loop and to save the first type in some temp variable and in a loop print a newline when it changes, but I am kinda stuck.

edit2:

after taking a break and then coming back i managed to fix the problem, and even without having a blank line in beginning. the problem was that i had to define oldTransport in main-class :) ofc you couldnt have known how my structure was. thank you hovercraft of eel :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than printing the line via `System.out.print(...)` *get* the line and put it into a variable. Split it via the `String#split(...)` method, and compare the first part obtained (the String in the [0] spot of the array obtained from split) with the previous String's first part (that was also saved to a variable). If different, make a new line before printing the line out.

Also, if you are going to extract a nextLine() from the scanner, *check* for a hasNextLine(), not hasNext().

In pseudocode

```
String oldTransportation gets assigned ""
while the scanner has a next line
   String variable line gets scanner's next line
   String array called tokens gets this line split on ":"
   String newTransportation gets the [0] item in the tokens array
   Check if newTransportation equals(...) oldTransportation, 
       if different, call System.out.println().
   print the line variable String
   oldTransportation gets assigned newTransportation
end while scanner...
```

Comment: my edit is how i interpreted your pseudo-code, but it doesnt seem to work. at what part did it go wrong? i mean the first time it wouldnt print the line because "" isnt equal "car" and thus go to the else:
write a new line and give oldTime the value "car".

Comment: @Yaman: If it's not a new transportation type, you're doing the opposite of what you need to do. You need to `System.out.print(line)` not do a `System.out.println()`. It's just how logic would dictate you should do it.

Comment: yeah ofcourse, i didnt mean to do that, i want my types on the same line not a new line for every. i was trying to change some things and experimented & added prints for debugging.
doesnt work though, editted the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Lets keep track of the previous type.

```
String lastTypeName = "";
for(Types filename: TypeTable) {
     if(!lastTypeName.equals(filename.toString()) {
          lastTypeName = filename.toString();
          System.out.println();
     }
     Scanner s = new Scanner(filename.toString());
     while (s.hasNext()) {
         System.out.print(s.nextLine()+ " ");
     }
     s.close();
}
```

A line break will get printed before the first line, but maybe that is not a problem.

Comment: yeah, i tried your first but it didnt really work out either. it seems simple though as im trying to keep it with scanners and other easy-maintained tools as im newbie.